# how to show optional screen instead of main screen at app start up

Tags: blackberry

My app has has an option to show screen-B instead of screen-A (default main) at app start up.
First I tried pushScreen(screen-B) in screen-A's constructor which resulted in display stack has screen-A on top and then screen-B..

What I want to do is:
At start up if the option is on, show screen-B (stack has screen-B then screen-A so that Escape key would lead to screen-A)

What would be the right way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider pushing B a little bit later in the process, in the onUiEngineAttached method:

```
class ScreenA extends Screen {
    ...
    protected void onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached) {
        if (attached) {
            // check condition and push B as appropriate
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. By this time (onUiEngineAttached), screen A had been pushed on stack top so I could push/pop screen B. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When the application starts, in the UiApplication class make the following:

```
class UiApp extends UiApplication {
    UiApp() {
        if (yourCondition)
            //start A
        else
            //start B
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        UiApp app = new UiApp();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }
}
```